# How to schedule to run testng.xml file on terminal on linux environment?

Tags: linux, java, scheduling, selenium

I have scripted a Selenium automation testcase. I have generated the testng.xml file which should be executed on the linux terminal at a particular time of my need. Say I want to schdule to execute the testng.xml file on terminal at 11pm everyday.

Comment: Why do you need terminal? If you need environment vars you can set them in script run by cron

Comment: Because I want to schedule the execution to run at a specific time. In order to do that I thought executing/running the script on the terminal would make it easier to schedule.

Comment: I do not know easier scheduling system than cron. Please provide the script and schedule times to be able to help you.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have scripted and generated the test script into a testng.xml file. So that I could execute it on the terminal. The location of the testng.xml file be like: /home/kasturi/workspace/app. What I do in order to run the script on the terminal is I first do to the particular directory via the command: cd /home/dananja/workspace/simsapp. Then I put this command to execute the script: java -cp "./lib/*:./bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml. I want to schedule that manual activity. I hope you get my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Authomation of the task can be done on this way:
Create in your home directory a script (with name script.sh for example) which contain:

```
#do not forget to set propper path to java executable
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
source /home/dananja/.bash_profile
cd /home/dananja/workspace/simsapp
$JAVA -cp "./lib/*:./bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

And in cron (via command `crontab -e`) add record like this:

```
0 23 * * * /home/dananja/script.sh
```

To make your script executable do not forget to exec (once)

```
chmod +x /home/dananja/script.sh
```

Comment: Thank you @Romeo I tried as you suggested. But it didn't work. I want to automate the process of opening the terminal and go to the particular directory and execute the script command...

Comment: The execution of the selenium script should run in the terminal.

Comment: Please provide the logs from cron log when you exec the script. And did you set execution flag on the script?

Comment: I didn't do any such thing. I mean I'm not so much into Linux. I'm not aware of cron log or what do you mean by execution flag? Please assist

Comment: The usual place for cron log is file `/var/log/cron`. And maybe you will need to be root user to see it.